# Winter Bash 2015 - the Hat Competition

Tags: discussion, hats

The last three years UX.SE participated in **Winter Bash**, which lets our users earn and wear hats on their user profile image. You earn hats through participation in asking questions, answering questions, getting up-votes, voting, commenting and sharing to mention a few things. Exactly the same things you’re doing here to earn reputation and badges. However, there is a twist; you don’t know what will earn hats. Suddenly, it just appears in a hat-gallery where you can pick the hat of the day. It’s all up to you, hat or no hat. You can choose not to wear any of earned hats.

Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event we run every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make our communities awesome.

Therefore, we’re announcing **Winter Bash 2015**!

## Winter Bash Leaderboard

[image]

## Winter Bash Hats Collection (2014)

A few of the available hats

[image]
[image]

## Winter Bash Hat Example (2014)

[image] [image] [image] [image]

## Details

This event will run from December 14 to January 3, 2016. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

## Don’t like hats?

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the UX.SE will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: My profile pic already has a hat, because it is Paddington Bear.

But this sounds like fun!

Comment: @YvonneAburrow My Profile image too has a well known red hat. Gotta change it before the 14th :-)

Comment: it does indeed - but my profile pic is also my Google+ one and I am very fond of it

Comment: Well, it's on! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @JonW Merry Christmas Jon *<:-)

Comment: I wish the winter bash hats never went away